# FSI caches something unwanted?

Tags: xml, f#, f#-interactive

I have some code in F# to validate an XML against schemas. The code is as below:

```ml
module IA.HelperScripts.ValidateXmlSchema
open System.IO
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Schema

let dictionary = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
let solutionPath = dictionary.Substring(0, dictionary.LastIndexOf('\\', dictionary.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1))
let schemaFolder = solutionPath + "\\Schemas"
let errorMessages = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
let schemas = new XmlSchemaSet()

let LoadSchema (schemaPath : string) (schemas : XmlSchemaSet) =
    use stream = new StreamReader(schemaPath)
    use xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream)
    let schema = XmlSchema.Read(xmlReader, null)
    schemas.Add(schema)

let Validate (xmlPath : string) =
    for schemaPath in Directory.GetFiles(schemaFolder) do
        LoadSchema schemaPath schemas |> ignore

    let settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.Schemas <- schemas
    settings.ValidationType <- ValidationType.Schema
    settings.ValidationEventHandler.AddHandler(fun o (e: ValidationEventArgs) -> 
        errorMessages.AppendFormat("{0} at position {1} of line {2}.", e.Message, e.Exception.LinePosition, e.Exception.LineNumber).AppendLine() |> ignore)

    use xmlStream = new StreamReader(xmlPath)
    use xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, settings)
    let document = new XmlDocument()
    document.Load(xmlReader) |> ignore

    let result = errorMessages.ToString()

    match result with
    | r when r.Length > 0 -> printfn "Error: \r\n%s" result
    | _ -> printfn "Validation Passed"
```

And I have another fsx file which load above fs file and execute the validate function. The code is as below:

```ml
#load "ValidateXmlSchema.fs"
open System.Reflection
open System.Collections.Generic


fsi.ShowDeclarationValues <- false

IA.HelperScripts.ValidateXmlSchema.Validate @"D:\t\IA\XmlForValidation.xml"
```

When I select all and Alt+Enter, it works fine every time. After first time run all of the script file, then I just select the last line for calling Validate function, It fails with following error:

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: **The global element 'http://tempuri.org/BaseSchema:PartnerFeed' has already been declared.**
>      at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
>      at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaException e)
>      at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.RecompileSchemaSet()
>      at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.Init()
>      at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator..ctor(XmlNameTable nameTable, XmlSchemaSet schemas, IXmlNamespaceResolver namespaceResolver, XmlSchemaValidationFlags validationFlags)
>      at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.SetupValidator(XmlReaderSettings readerSettings, XmlReader reader, XmlSchemaObject partialValidationType)
>      at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlResolver xmlResolver, XmlReaderSettings readerSettings, XmlSchemaObject partialValidationType)
>      at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.AddValidation(XmlReader reader)
>      at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(TextReader input, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext)
>      at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(TextReader input, XmlReaderSettings settings, String baseUri)
>      at FSI_0004.IA.HelperScripts.ValidateXmlSchema.Validate(String xmlPath) in D:\ECOVSO\KSP\Dev\KSP\Tools\HelperScripts\ValidateXmlSchema.fs:line 28
>      at .$FSI_0006.main@()
>   Stopped due to error

I think the error may caused by the FSI session cached something and then it found the XmlDocument has duplicate root element. But actually I declared the XmlStream and XmlReader by "use". Please help me figure out why I must reset the interactive session or re-run all script to make the function work.

Comment: it seems to me that you add all files you find in that particular folder as schemas - and two (or more) seem to share a `PartnerFeed` definition - don't think that this has anything to do with F#-interactive or a root-element at all - why not just debug it (for example enter a few `printfn` for logging, or just make it into a console app and debug it using VS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `Validate`, it calls `LoadSchema`, which adds the schema to `schemas`. Therefore, if you call `Validate` twice, `schemas` will end up containing two copies of the same schema. No wonder that causes an error.

Comment: Yes, this is the root cause. Thanks a lot.